# Derived class not calling member function of base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, c++14

Say I have a class `event_base` defined like so

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event_base{
    public:
        using delegate_type = std::function<void(Args...)>;
        using id_type = size_t;

    protected:
        std::vector<std::tuple<delegate_type, id_type>> m_funcs;
};
```

Then I have some derived classes based on whether an event is mutable and/or callable

mutable:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event_mutable: public event_base<Args...>{
    public:
        using id_type = typename event_base<Args...>::id_type;

        template<FunctorType>
        id_type connect(FunctorType &&f){
            this->m_funcs.emplace_back(f, ++m_last_id);
            return m_last_id;
        }

        bool disconnect(id_type id){
            for(auto iter = begin(this->m_funcs); iter != end(this->m_funcs); ++iter)
                if(std::get<1>(*iter) == id){
                    this->m_funcs.erase(iter);
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
};
```

callable:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event_callable: public event_base<Args...>{
    public:
        void operator()(Args ... args) const{
            for(auto iter = this->m_funcs.rbegin(); iter != this->m_funcs.rend(); ++iter)
                (std::get<0>(*this))(args...);
        }
};
```

and for both:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event: public event_mutable<Args...>, public event_callable<Args...>{};
```

Casting between the types and such works fine, but for some reason when I call an event like this ...

```
event<int> int_ev;
int_ev.connect(/* ... some function ... */);
int_ev(5);
```

... the connected function isn't called!

This leads me to believe that the `operator()` defined in `event_callable` isn't being called correctly or the `vector` `m_funcs` isn't being traversed within the method.

What am I doing wrong here and/or why isn't the `vector` being iterated over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a diamond-shaped inheritance, which means that in your situation, `event` gets two versions of `m_funcs`; one coming from `event_mutable`, and one from `event_callable`. Therefore, `connect()` populates `event_mutable::m_funcs`, and `operator()` searches in `event_callable::m_funcs`. You should use virtual inheritance to overcome this problem:

```
class event_callable: public virtual event_base { ... };
class event_mutable: public virtual event_base { ... };

class event: public event_callable, public event_mutable { ... };
```

Comment: Good lord. Thank you. I was actually reading about diamond-shaped inheritance last week and was thinking about how I couldn't see it happening within one of my designs.